# How to change url in parse.com android?

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-parser, back4app

Hi As parse beeen officially going to close, I am using an alternative as back4app. So in back4app, [documentation](http://docs.back4app.com/docs/parse-migration/parse-sdk/how-to-update-parse-sdk-for-android/) says

Use this code and change url instead of https://api.parse.com

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(myContext)
.applicationId("YOUR_APP_ID")
.clientKey("YOUR_CLIENT_KEY")
.server("https://parseapi.back4app.com")
```

But I couldn't use the above line, as it throws compile error as

com.parse.Pars.Builder Configuration has private access in com.parse.Parse.Configuration in the first line of initialize method.

Then How to change and apply it.

Comment: Are you using android sdk 1.13.0?

Comment: I think you are using below 1.13.0, try clean project and rebuild, or check is there any low version jar file.

Comment: i downloaded from [latest parse](https://parse.com/downloads/android/Parse/latest) link. where it mentioned version as 1.13.0

Comment: it will not work in 1.13.0? let me try by integrating below version.

Comment: even i tried [gradle](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/existing)  too.    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+' still no use.

Comment: I think you are using 1.12.0 or 1.13.0 correctly. The sdk version is ok, only these 2 version contain Parse.Configuration. Sorry, I haven't mention that error says you have call the constructor of "Parse.Configuration", and this constructor is a private method. You should call build() to get the Parse.Configuration instance. See have you use build() in your code. Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(myContext)
    .applicationId("YOUR_APP_ID")
    .clientKey("XXX)
    .server("http://localhost:1337/parse/")
    .build()
);

Comment: omg. thanks for pointing out mistake.. :) please add as answer.. i will accept it and close this question..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are using 1.12.0 or 1.13.0 correctly. The sdk version is ok, only these 2 version contain Parse.Configuration.

The error says you have called the constructor of "Parse.Configuration", and this constructor is a private method.

You should call build() to get the Parse.Configuration instance. See have you use build() in your code.

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(myContext)
    .applicationId("YOUR_APP_ID")
    .clientKey(null)
    .server("http://localhost:1337/parse/") 
    .build()
);
```